# Does 98:6 contradict 8:22 about who are the worst of creatures?

Tags: quran, hadith, tafseer

Emphasis mine

> 98:6 Indeed, they who disbelieved among the People of the Scripture and the polytheists will be in the fire of Hell, abiding eternally therein. Those are THE WORST OF CREATURES.

> 8:22
> Indeed, THE WORST OF LIVING CREATURES in the sight of Allāh are the deaf and dumb who do not use reason [i.e., the disbelievers].
> — Saheeh International

Comment: What is the contradiction?

Comment: @The Z I think I myself figured out the meaning when I was writing a reply to you. "THE deaf dumb and blind" can mean a specific group, not necessarily everyone who is such

Comment: Maybe the second verse needs an explanation as deaf and dumb are related to "reason" else there's neither a contradiction nor an issue with this verse. Note that "**the** worst" here is necessray in the English transaltion while in Arabic the term is not specific. A better translation could be "among the worst".

Comment: Please edit your post and make clear what is contradictory as per your interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

With the preceding verse, we read 8:21-22 (translation by Wahuddin Khan)

> Do not be like those who say, "We hear," but pay no heed to what they hear -- the worst creatures in God's eyes are those who are deaf and dumb, and who possess no understanding.

It becomes clear that the verse doesn't refer to handicapped people but to those who do not want to listen to the Word. The usage of the expression "deaf" in this sense is already established from earlier prophecy, so that it has surely directly been understood in this sense.

Now, those who close their mind to the Word of God are notorious disbelievers.

The other verse also refers to disbelievers.

The word sharra is a noun meaning evil. It need not be understood as an absolute superlative (worst) that excludes other evil, like those mentioned in 98:6 (where the same word for evil is used).

Comment: I know that it doesn't refer to actual blind etc.. people. That wasn't my point.

Comment: So neither actually exclude eachother?

Comment: No, they don't exclude each other